Relative Jacobian as a ramified holomorphic quotient
Let $f:X \to S$ be an elliptic fibration with only $m$ singular fibers of type $I_1$ at the set of points $\lbrace s_1,\cdots, s_m \rbrace$ of $S$. In the paper "On Compact Analytic Surfaces: II", chapter 9 of Kodaira (also in Chapter V, section 9 of the book "Compact Complex Surfaces" of W.Barth, C.Peters and A. Van de Ven or in the paper "Algebraic surfaces holomorphically dominable by $\mathbb{C}^2$" of G.Buzzard and S.Lu), there is a construction of relative Jacobian $\mathrm{Jac(f)}$ associated to $X$ by considering the quotient: $R^1f_*O_X/R^1f_*\mathbb{Z}_X$. Since $E = R^1f_*O_X$ is of rank 1, it is a holomorphic line bundle over $S$, and if we assume $S$ is $\mathbb{C}$ (which is the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$), then $E$ is trivial and we can identify it with $\mathbb{C}^2$ and $\mathrm{Jac(f)}:= \mathbb{C}^2/R^1f_*\mathbb{Z}_X$ a holomorphic quotient. At a point $s \in S$, $(R^1f_*\mathbb{Z}_X)_s$ is $\mathbb{Z}^2$ if $X_s$ is an elliptic curve and is $\mathbb{Z}$ if  $X_s$ is a nodal curve. At each smooth fiber $X_s$, $(R^1f_*\mathbb{Z}_X)_s= H^1(X_s,\mathbb{Z})= \Lambda_s$ is a lattice in $E_s = \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathrm{Jac(f)}_s$ is the elliptic curve $X_s$ since $\mathrm{Jac(f)}_s = \mathbb{C}/\Lambda_s$. At the singular fiber $X_{s_i}$, $\mathrm{Jac(f)}_{s_i}$ is the quotient $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}$, which is $\mathbb{C}^*$. Thus the fibers of the fibration $\mathrm{Jac(f)} \to S$ are the Jacobian of the fibers of $f$, and $\mathrm{Jac(f)} = X - \lbrace x_1,\cdots,x_m \rbrace$ with $x_i$ are singular points of the singular fibers $s_i$. Notice that $\mathrm{Jac(f)} \to S$ is a smooth fibration.
Consider the quotient map: $q:E=\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2/R^1f_*\mathbb{Z}_X = \mathrm{Jac(f)}$. It is not hard to see that outside of the "singular locus" $\mathrm{Sing}(q)=\mathrm{Jac(f)}_{s_1} \cup \cdots \cup \mathrm{Jac(f)}_{s_m}$, $q$ is unramified, and the maps $q_s: E_s \to \mathrm{Jac(f)}_s$ are all holomorphic covering map pointwise. Would it be true if the holomorphic quotient map $q:E=\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathrm{Jac(f)}$ ramified at $\mathrm{Sing}(q)$? Would there be any simple way to see that $q$ is not unramified?
